# Find longest consequent digits pattern in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

`var mystring = http://www.myurl.com/45/abc/12345/place/123456`

How can I find, with regex, the longest consequent digits pattern `anywhere` in that string?

The output should be `123456`, as If i know the length exactly:

```
mystring.match(/\d{6}/g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
console.log( mystring.match(/\d+/g).sort((a, b) => b - a)[0] );
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that a regex itself matches a chunk of text during a matching operation, and does not track the matches by itself. It is not possible to match *the longest* digit chunk with a mere regex.

Extract all the digit chunks, then sort the values in a descending order and grab the first item:

```js
var mystring = "http://www.myurl.com/45/abc/12345/place/123456";
console.log(mystring.match(/\d+/g).sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0]);
```

Note there is no need using a capturing group (the `(` and `)` should be removed as we are not using the captured value.

The `+` quantifier matches *one or more occurrences* of the pattern quantified (that is, `\d`, or `[0-9]` here, a digit).

Answer (score 2):

Extract all the sequences of numbers, then find the longest in the resulting array.

```
function byLength(a,b) { return a.length > b.length ? -1 : a.length == b.length ? 0 : 1 }
var digit_sequences = mystring.match(/(\d+)/g).sort(byLength)
digit_sequences[0] // '123456'
```